# View labels in right-to-left languages in R 3.5.3 shiny ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm using R 3.5.3, and shiny 1.2.0, and I need to view "ggplot2" graph with labels in Hebrew.

For some reason, the labels in Hebrew appear reversed.

In previous versions of R it never happened.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(temp,aes(x=Phrase,y=Freq))+scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) 
lapply(strwrap(x, width = 25, simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse="\n"),limits = temp$Phrase[order(temp$Freq)])+
geom_bar(color="darkblue", fill="lightblue",stat="identity")+ coord_flip()
```

There is some way to fix it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question as I was seeing the same thing.
What I did was manually reverse the labels:

```
heb_label <- "אני"
splits <- strsplit(heb_label, "")[[1]]
reversed <- rev(splits)
final_heb_label <- paste(reversed, collapse = "")
```

Based on code by Andrew Treadway at [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/four-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-r/)

I like at as it uses base R, and doesn't burden my shiny app's dependencies.